# Change dates in list with multiple dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, date, dictionary

I have a list with multiple dictionaries, like the following:

```
[{'Date': '6-1-2017', 'Rate':'0.3', 'Type':'A'},
 {'Date': '6-1-2017', 'Rate':'0.4', 'Type':'B'},
 {'Date': '6-1-2017', 'Rate':'0.6', 'Type':'F'},
 {'Date': '6-1-2017', 'Rate':'0.1', 'Type':'B'}
]
```

I would now like to change the dates, because they need to be in the format 'yyymmdd', which starts at 1900-01-01. In other words, I would like to change the '6-1-2017' to '1170106'.

As this has to be done every week (with the then current date), I do not want to change this by hand. So next week, '13-1-2017' has to be transformed into '1170113'.

Anyone ideas how to do this? I have tried several things, but I can't even get my code to select the date-values of all dictionaries.

Many thanks!

Comment: Show what you have tried, and how it came up short.

Comment: `1170106` is not the same as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: what even us `1170106`?

Comment: @MattDMo, you are completely right. I need the `yyymmdd` format. I'll change the post.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint, it is the 117th year after 1900, and then month 01 and day 06. So 1170106.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `datetime` module, which provides a lot of functionality to manipulate datetime objects including converting datetime to string and the way back, accessing different components of the datetime object, etc:

```
from datetime import datetime

for l in lst:
    l['Date'] = datetime.strptime(l['Date'], "%d-%m-%Y")
    l['Date'] = str(l['Date'].year - 1900) + l['Date'].strftime("%m%d")

lst
#[{'Date': '1170106', 'Rate': '0.3', 'Type': 'A'},
# {'Date': '1170106', 'Rate': '0.4', 'Type': 'B'},
# {'Date': '1170106', 'Rate': '0.6', 'Type': 'F'},
# {'Date': '1170106', 'Rate': '0.1', 'Type': 'B'}]
```